# How do I achieve the Arms Dealer Trophy in MW3?

Tags: achievements, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

The description says: "Buy all items from the Survival Weapon Armory", which is simple enough.

My question is about the details: Do I have to buy every individual attachment for each individual weapon? Or perhaps say, if I buy the Red Dot Sight for the M4, will that be the only Red Dot Sight I have to buy to accomplish the achievement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to buy all attachments at least ***once*** as well as the weapons. Buying a Red Dot (or any attachment) for one gun does counts for all. One of those dedication type achievements.

If you're struggling, make sure you have each type of grenade launcher too.

Good luck!

[**Source & Little more Help**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qeDuadJHK6g&feature=related)

Answer (score 4):

You only have to buy the attachments once, if the attachment is the same across multiple guns.  This means that you can buy the Red Dot sight once, for one weapon, and then you won't have to buy it again on another gun.

The exception to this is the grenade launchers, which are different on 3 ARs:

- AK47 (GP25 grenade launcher)
- M4A1 (M203 grenade launcher)
- SCAR (M320 grenade launcher)

You must buy *all three* of the grenade launchers for this.

You don't have to do this in a single survival match, it's cumulative.  Keeping track of what you've bought can be tricky, however.  You'll need to make it to level 50 before you'll unlock everything.  Some suggestions I read include:

- Buy a whole class of weapons out at once, so that you know you've gotten them all.
- Get a whole bunch of money (it would take $124,000 by one user's count to afford everything at once - yikes!)

Note that you also must buy the weapons you generally pick up or start with.  The Five-Seven is the starting pistol, so buying it might not be obvious, and you'll generally find the 1887 in the first round, and some SMGs and ARs are dropped by enemies in later rounds.

I have not yet gotten this one myself.  I looked at some guides in order to obtain this information, but I believe it is reliable given the number of independent confirmations.  Some of this is detailed in this thread on [Xbox360Achievemvents](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3/achievement/61441-Arms-Dealer.html), and a pretty good guide is over here on [TrueAchievements](http://www.trueachievements.com/a157676/arms-dealer-achievement.htm).

Comment: Great Answer 86, Id like to accept yours for the extra detail but In-All-Fairness Peter answered the question completly and did it first. Voted it up though.

Answer (score 1):

This achievement can be done in single or multiplayer and can be done over many different missions (i.e., *not* in one mission). Make sure you buy the original handgun you are given. Picking up a gun does *not* count. You only need to buy the attachment for one gun, *not* for every gun.

What you need to get:

**HANDGUNS:**
Five Seven,
USP 45,
MP412,
Desert Eagle,
.44 Magnum,
P99

**MACHINE PISTOLS:**
G18,
Skorpion,
MP9,
FM99

**ASSAULT RIFLES:**
M4A1,
M16A4,
SCAR-l,
ACR 6.8,
AK47,
FAD,
G36C,
CM901,
MK14,
Type95

**SUB MACHINE GUNS:**
MP5,
UMP5,
MP7,
PM-9,
PM90M1,
P90

**LMGs:**
M60E4,
PKP Pecheneg,
MK46,
L86LSW,
MG36

**SNIPERS:**
MSR,
Dragunov,
RSASS,
L118A,
AS50,
Barrett .50 Cal

**SHOTGUNS:**
Model 1887,
USAS,
SPAS12,
KSG12,
AA-12,
Striker

**ATTACHMENTS:**
Holographic Sight,
Red Dot Sight,
ACOG Scope,
M203 Grenade Launcher (e.g. M4A1),
M320 Grenade Launcher (e.g. ACR),
GP25 Grenade Launcher (e.g. AK47),
Grip,
Shotgun